# I have a problem with Roman page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing a thesis and in LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS AND SYMBOLS I have well-known and specific abbreviation. well-known abbreviation has Roman page numbering but another one has normal numbering. it should have Roman numbering as well.

this is how I coded.

```
\chapter*{List of abbreviations and symbols}
\markboth{}{}                                % no headers
\textbf{Well-Known Abbreviations}
\begin{termlist}
blah blah blah
\end{termlist} 
\newpage
\textbf{Speciﬁc Abbreviations For This Thesis}
\begin{termlist}
blah blah blah
\end{termlist}
```

I have the same issue with and without `\newpage`

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post a compilable document, not just fragments only. I have removed the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

The command `\pagenumbering{roman}` should do the intended.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{termlist}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{The main thesis chapters}
  blah blah blah

  \chapter*{List of abbreviations and symbols}

  \pagenumbering{roman}     % restart page numbers: i, ii, ...
  \markboth{}{}             % no headers

  \textbf{Well-Known Abbreviations}
  \begin{termlist}
    \item blah blah blah
  \end{termlist} 
  \newpage

  \textbf{Speciﬁc Abbreviations For This Thesis}
  \begin{termlist}
    \item blah blah blah
  \end{termlist} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but it's not working. I have lots of things before that such as abstract and etc. if I add \pagenumbering the same way you said, it would be reset. the problem is that I have two termlist. I guess it breaks the \pagenumbering

Comment: @Matthew : If you want to continue the page numbering, you can use `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}` instead of `\pagenumbering{roman}`. Further, to have braces around the numbers, use `\renewcommand{\thepage}{(\roman{page})}`